# Did people in Tamriel really live for about thousands of years?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-series

According to this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/48229/are-any-skyrim-characters-carried-over-from-oblivion-or-earlier), NPC's from Morrowind and Oblivion are moved to Skyrim. Since Morrowind takes place in 3E 427, Oblivion takes place in 3E 433, and Skyrim takes place in 4E 201; these people might have lived for a hundred or even a thousand years, since a person in real life's life spam is a maximum of 100 years old [rare chance older than that]. Could people in the Elder Scrolls times really live about a hundred or thousand years old, or did the gods let them live for this much years?

Comment: Note that in the linked question, several of the characters listed are non your run of the mill mortal, to say the least. I'm no TES historian, but I think this question might be based on faulty premises. Is there any mortal NPC explicitly stated or implied to be the same one seen in a previous Elder Scrolls game?

Comment: Well the only evidence is about the date in the games.

Comment: I mean I know in the events of oblivion, a prisoner becomes the Champion or Cyrodiil, and then in the Shivering Isles DLC he becomes Sheogorath, and then in 200 years he's found again in Skyrim and proof Sheogorath is actually the Champion is the he knows about the Oblivion Crisis and what I put above.

Comment: Yeah, but Sheogorath is, like, *literally* a god.

Answer (score 8):

Let's go by the list:

- Dervenin: Is a servant of an insane god, lifespan extensions aren't unreasonable.
- Neloth: Is a mer (elf), there's no confirmed information about an elfs lifespan, but it's long so this is unsurprising.
- Karstaag: I wouldn't call a ghost living.
- Sheogorath: Is a Deadric prince, Deadra are immortal.
- Carius: Ressurected by a necromancer, not really alive.
- Uderfrykte: Is a troll, which might live longer, but it's not the same creature. They're just references to previous versions.
- Sinderion: Is a *skeleton*
- M'aiq the Liar: Is an easter egg, extraordinary lifespan for an easter egg (they're usually eaten much faster!)
- Ulfgar: Is an immortal nord, already 500 years old in bloodmoon.
- Jiub: Ghost.
- Barbas: Deadric familiar, also immortal.
- Lucien Lachance: Another ghost.
- Shadowmere: Is some kind of evil, immortal horse. In the lore, so not surprising the immortal horse lives.
- Nelacar: Mer, they live a really long time.
- Etienne, Fallaise, Isobel: They've become hag ravens, which also grant an extended livespan.
- Night Mother: She was a ghost in Oblivion and a corpse in Skyrim, not alive either.

So yeah, except for an easter egg, gods, elfs and dead people, humans lived a mostly normal lifespan as far as I can tell.

Comment: Okay, so only some right?

Comment: Define some? Unless you get cursed (Ulfgar) or some god plays with you (Dervenin) humans live for regular human livetimes (well, regular now, a medieval era society like the TES games portray would generally live shorter lives than shown in the games. Apparently magic is about as good as modern medicine!)

Comment: Oh, even Dervenin is a bosmer, so the only one on the list that's actually a human with a long lifespan is Ulfgar. And he wasn't alive in Skyrim, as you only see him in Sovengard (the Nord afterlife)

Comment: Ulfgar wasn't exactly 500 years old. He said that they were looking for a portal 500 years ago. If he was exactly that, he would of been born a that time. he must of lived a large amount.